# MDS and Windows 8

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

MDS was working fine in Windows 7, but after i upgraded my OS to Windows 8 MDS stop working. when i click on MDS icon a cmd window pop up and then disapear and simulator is not able to connect to internet. 
Note: Java directory folder didn't change, it still in the same path.

Comment: I'm not sure it is compatible with W8 (should be), but check if Windows built-in firewall is blocking it.

Comment: i disabled the firewall plus antivirus before and didn't work either.

Comment: I don't know what could be happening, but remember than most modern simulators can also work without MDS. They connect as if they were using direct-TCP mode.

Comment: i tried that too, no luck, but thank you i found the soultion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reinstall MDS and now it works prefect.